# Retrieved token Value is not being passed correctly - backslashes and pipes changed to percent and numbers

Tags: jmeter

I've got a page response which contains a "contextToken" as below. Notice the pipes and double backslashes:

[image]

I use a boundary extractor to successfully retrieve this value:
[image]

The debugger correctly shows the extracted value with double backslashes and pipes:

[image]

However the request where I'm using this token has substituted the pipes and backlashes with % signs and numbers:

[image]

Since the token is not right on submission of page I get a failure. How do I retain and pass the contextToken exactly as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's a matter of visualisation only, the real problem lives somewhere else, you can check what exactly you're sending using an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), here is an example:

[image]

Use your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) in order to compare the token from the previous response and the token which is being sent with the next request, it might be the case you will need to transform it somehow like [URL Encode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode), [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), [escape HTML characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__escapeHtml) or something like this, if that will be the case refer to [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn how to use JMeter Functions for on-the-fly data manipulations

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have another question for you if you can help please :-)

Comment: Actually I figured out the problem I was having for the other question so I deleted it. It was interesting since the value extracted by the extractor had extra backslashes. This meant subsequent posts using the extracted value were erroring. I fixed this by removing the extra slashes and it's working now.